# Dynamic params in ember component

Tags: ember.js

I am having a component in which the params are passed while rendering it. It will have dynamic params, so i cant exactly get it by its name. I searched many posts but didn't find any suitable.

> **Application.hbs**

```
{{small-button type="small" edges="curved"}}
```

> **small-button.js**

```
Ember.Component.extend({
 tagName: "button",
 didInsertElement: function(){
   //need to get the dynamic params
 }
});
```

*I dont know about the param key. how can i get all the params form my component `button`*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get it using `this.get('type')` this will return `small` . what do you mean by dynamic params ?

Comment: `type` will not a constant one. It may be `class` or anything else. i dpnt know which key will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible think of any other alternatives for this use case. for now I am going to suggest `this.attrs` only for you not for others.

```
didInsertElement: function(){
   //need to get the dynamic params
   console.log(' Params keys ',Object.keys(this.attrs));
   console.log(' Param values ', Object.values(this.attrs));
 }
```

Read this - https://locks.svbtle.com/to-attrs-or-not-to-attrs

> So, why shouldn’t you use `attrs` in Classic Components? Because in Classic Components `attrs` already existed, and is used internally to manage component bindings and might not be exactly what you need. While you should be mostly fine using it for actions, you’ll have problems if you use it for attributes, so it’s easier to use the current APIs than to keep this in mind.

Comment: so, can i use `attrs` or you are suggesting something else?

Comment: I dont think of any other recommended solutions for getting dynamic params like you wanted. In general `this.attrs` is for Glimmer components(`<my-component>`) but that's still not yet landed in Ember.

Comment: In your case, for external attributes alone, so you can use it with cautious.